# Execute a shell script with input parameter

Tags: linux, shell

The shell script below asks the user for hour and minute. When you enter these two inputs it schedules for imaging. When I try to run this script as root like:
`bash -x /run/opt/corp/cmtg/2.0.0/sesm/admin/scripts/configure_gwcautoimaging 13 56`. I get the following error: `typset:'13': not a valid identifier and typset:'56': not a valid identifier.`

My question is how can I execute this script with its parameter in one line. I also tried `./run/opt/corp/cmtg/2.0.0/sesm/admin/scripts/configure_gwcautoimaging << "16 16"` and `sh /run/opt/corp/cmtg/2.0.0/sesm/admin/scripts/configure_gwcautoimaging 16 50` but they didn't work I got same error.

```
#!/bin/bash
    DEBUG="";
    #DEBUG="set -x";
    eval $DEBUG;
    typeset inputHour=2;
    typeset inputMinute=0;
    typeset crontabsFile="/etc/crontab";
    typeset tmp_crontabsFile="/tmp/crontab.tmp";
    typeset imagingsh=$BIN_DIR/autoimaging.sh;
    function validateNumber
    {
      eval $DEBUG;
      typeset -i vInput=$1;
      if [[ $? != 0 ]]
      then
        return 1;
      fi
      typeset -i vBase=$2;
      if [[ $? != 0 ]]
      then
        return 1;
      fi

      if (( vInput < 0 || vInput >= vBase ))
      then
        return 1;
      fi
      return 0;
    }
    function updatecrontabs
    {
      eval $DEBUG;
      typeset hour=$1;
      typeset minute=$2;

      #remove any entries that already have the autoimaging.sh
      /bin/grep -v "${imagingsh}" $crontabsFile > ${tmp_crontabsFile};   

      cat <<- EOF >> $tmp_crontabsFile
    $inputMinute $inputHour * * * $imagingsh
    EOF
      crontab ${tmp_crontabsFile}  
      if [[ $? != 0 ]]
      then
        return 1;
      fi
      cp ${tmp_crontabsFile} ${crontabsFile}; 
    }
    # If this script is invoked with two parameters, parse the two parameters as Hour and Minute
    # Otherwise, get input from user.
    if [[ $# != 2 ]]
    then
      echo " Configure Auto Imaging ";
      while ( true )
      do
        echo -n "Please input the hour when the Auto Imaging is to be executed: ";
        read inputHour
        if [[ -n $inputHour ]]
        then
          validateNumber $inputHour 24;
          if [[ $? == 0 ]]
          then
            break;
          else
            echo "You must input the number between 0 and 24";
        echo " ";
          fi
        else
          echo "You must input the number between 0 and 24";
          echo " ";
         fi 
      done
      while ( true )
      do
        echo -n "Please input the minute when the Auto Imaging is to be executed: ";
        read inputMinute
        if [[ -n $inputMinute ]]
        then
          validateNumber $inputMinute 60;
          if [[ $? == 0 ]]
          then
            break;
          else
            echo "You must input the number between 0 and 60";
        echo " ";
          fi
        else
          echo "You must input the number between 0 and 60";
          echo " ";
        fi  
      done
    else
      inputHour=$1;
      inputMinute=$2;
      typeset vResult=validateNumber $inputHour 24;
      if [[ $vResult != 0 ]]
      then
        echo "The number for hour must be between 0 and 24";
        exit 1;
      fi
      vResult= validateNumber $inputMinute 60;
      if [[ $vResult != 0 ]]
      then
        echo "The number for minute must be between 0 and 60";
        exit 1;
      fi 
    fi
    # Begin update the entry: auto imaging in crontabs
    updatecrontabs $inputHour $inputMinute;
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]
    then
      echo "update crontabs successfully! The auto imaging will be executed at: " $inputHour ":" $inputMinute;
      echo " ";
    else
      echo "Errors happen during update crontabs";
      echo " "
      exit 1;
    fi
    rm ${tmp_crontabsFile} > /dev/null;
    exit 0;
```

Comment: learn to use shell debug/trace features, i.e. `set -vx; PS4='${LINENO} #>'` To turn off, use `set +vx;unset PS4`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited my code parts as below and it is working now:

```
validateNumber $inputHour 24;
      if [[ $? != 0 ]]
```

and

```
validateNumber $inputMinute 60;
      if [[ $? != 0 ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems suspicious:

```
typeset vResult=validateNumber $inputHour 24;
```

It doesn't call the function, you need to use `$(validateNumber $inputHour 24)` or backticks.

Similarly, the following line is probably wrong:

```
vResult= validateNumber $inputMinute 60;
```

It clears `$vResult` and calls `validateNumber` with `$inputMinute` and `60` as parameters.

I am able to get the same error if I call `typeset` with a number as the first argument, but I don't see such usage in your code. Are you sure you pasted the version that caused the problem?

```
a=12 ; typeset -i $a=b
bash: typeset: `12=b': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: Yes I am sure, When I execute it without parameters like: bash -x /run/opt/corp/cmtg/2.0.0/sesm/admin/scripts/configure_gwcautoimaging, it asks me Please input the hour when the GWC Auto Imaging is to be executed: and after I entered for hour it asks for minute that I want to enter.

Comment: @OscarSayin: Please, reduce the script as per [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/). I'm not going to run code that touches crontab files.